# What is the function of 先 in 我諗聽日先買飛嘅話一定買唔到 (cantonese)

Tags: usage, cantonese

In the sentence: 我諗聽日先買飛嘅話一定買唔到。

What is the function of “先”?

The original translation from a reference is “I don’t think you’ll be able to buy a ticket tomorrow.”

I do not understand the role of “先”, and can it be discarded?

Answer (score 3):

先 here is short for 先至

- 先(first)
- 至(then)

先至 (first then)= **till... then**

> 我諗*等到*聽日(**先**)買飛嘅話一定買唔到
>
> I think if we *wait* (**till**) tomorrow (**then**) to buy ticket we will certainly fail to buy any
>
> The word "等到" (wait) is implied

Example of difference between "先至/ 先" (till...then) and "先" (first/ for now)

做好功課(先至/先)准睇電視 - (Till) finish all the homework (then) allowed to watch TV.

你地坐吓等陣(先) - you guys sit for a while and wait (first/ for now)

- When "...先" is followed by a verb phrase, it is a short form of 先至, meaning "till ... then"
- When 先 is at the end of a words clause, it means "first" or "for now"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be discarded. You can say `我諗聽日買飛嘅話一定買唔到` and the meaning is the same. I'm not sure if it's "until", but I feel it's similar to "才“

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think (you/we)’ll be able to buy a ticket tomorrow.
我諗聽日買飛嘅話一定買唔到。

I don’t think (you/we)’ll be able to buy a ticket *if (you/we) wait until* tomorrow.
我諗聽日*先*買飛嘅話一定買唔到。